# What does $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^i}{i!}dx$mean?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, notation

I was reading a research paper and I came across this sentence which I didn't really understand.

We first cast Eq.1 into its standard form: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^i}{i!}dx$$
$$T^2-944T+155184-h=0$$
Eq. 1 is stated at the beginning of the paper and is the following:
$$h(T)=520(212-T)+{(212+T)}^2$$
What are the integral and sums supposed to mean and/or refer to?

Comment: Can you give us more context?  The integral doesn't converge and has apparently no relation to the equation involving $T$.

Comment: There really is no context that is why I was really confused, the research paper is about how boiling temperature of water $T$ is related to the height $h$.

Comment: A link to the paper or reference might help.

Comment: https://emckclac-my.sharepoint.com/:b:/g/personal/k1924766_kcl_ac_uk/ER_6oK5h0ntEgL1HFMvIXIMBQ1xnFH9pkWMVJqJhXkebXA?e=MZs6nH

Comment: That is incongruous.  I'm going to bet my money that equation (4) is an editorial goof.  The author was using a template of some sort and instead of replacing the integral, copied the format below.  Erasing the integral, makes the math easy and sensible.  So I don't think it belongs there.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the context, but $$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^i}{i!} = e^x$$
because the sum is the Taylor series of $e^x$.

If this is the case, the integral has a more clear meaning.

Comment: The first index of the sum should be $i=0$, otherwise you have $e^x-1$.

Comment: Yes, you are right.